# Framework7 Vue promise postJson CORS issue

Tags: php, vue.js, html-framework-7

I am attempting to create a simple application in Framework7 Vue. I am using the most recent version. I have a small api I am trying to get up and running but for some reason I can not test out my desired code. When I connect using promise.post, promise.get, promise.getJSON it works fine but if I try to use promise.postJSON it fails.  I can not figure out why CORS would reject only postJSON.

Does not work

```
self.$f7.request.promise.postJSON( self.webapi.login, { email: self.email, password: self.password } );
```

These Work

```
self.$f7.request.promise.getJSON( self.webapi.login, { email: self.email, password: self.password } );
self.$f7.request.promise.get( self.webapi.login, { email: self.email, password: self.password } );
self.$f7.request.promise.post( self.webapi.login, { email: self.email, password: self.password } );
```

PHP Headers in my API

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000");
```

Sample return from API

```
{"reply":"1","id":2,"token":";lk3984hq347y0q34h;q34kjhiq98u987oi4h","code":"123456"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GET requests will be generating [simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests), but POSTing JSON requires a non-safe `Content-Type` request header so will require a [preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests).

The API is failing to respond to the preflight in an acceptable way. The error message will tell you precisely how (typically it will respond with an unacceptable status code (such as a redirect or error) or will have missing or wrong `Access-Control-...` headers.